# Pydev debugger can't lauch: No module named '_pydevd_frame_eval.pydevd_frame_evaluator'

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Eclipse Version:

- Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
- PyDev Version:  5.9.0.201708101613

  on Windows 7 64x.

PyDev is launching my Django project normally, but PyDev debugger crashes:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\bureau.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.9.0.201708101613\pysrc_pydevd_frame_eval\pydevd_frame_eval_cython_wrapper.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from _pydevd_frame_eval.pydevd_frame_evaluator import frame_eval_func, stop_frame_eval, enable_cache_frames_without_breaks,
>   dummy_trace_dispatch ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   '_pydevd_frame_eval.pydevd_frame_evaluator'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\bureau.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.9.0.201708101613\pysrc\pydevd.py",
>   line 42, in 
>       from _pydevd_frame_eval.pydevd_frame_eval_main import frame_eval_func, stop_frame_eval, enable_cache_frames_without_breaks,
>   dummy_trace_dispatch   File
>   "C:\Users\bureau.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.9.0.201708101613\pysrc_pydevd_frame_eval\pydevd_frame_eval_main.py",
>   line 21, in 
>       from _pydevd_frame_eval.pydevd_frame_eval_cython_wrapper import frame_eval_func, stop_frame_eval, enable_cache_frames_without_breaks,
>   \   File
>   "C:\Users\bureau.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.9.0.201708101613\pysrc_pydevd_frame_eval\pydevd_frame_eval_cython_wrapper.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       frame_eval_func, stop_frame_eval, enable_cache_frames_without_breaks, dummy_trace_dispatch =
>   mod.frame_eval_func, mod.stop_frame_eval,
>   mod.enable_cache_frames_without_breaks, ValueError: not enough values
>   to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

*Note* : LiClipse and its debugger is launching normally.

The version for LiClipse:

- LiClipse 4.0.0.201706061723
- PyDev for Eclipse    5.8.0.201706061723

There may be a problem with PyDev August version indeed, compared to the June version. 
Is it possible to downgrade PyDev in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest pydev plugin (5.9.2.201708151115) fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've downgraded to PyDev 5.8 and it's working.

I hope the last version will be fixed soon.

How to do that:

1. uninstall PyDev
2. download PyDev 5.8 (the Marketplace in Eclipse shows the 5.8 version but strangely it still installs the 5.9 version):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/PyDev%205.8.0/

3. then install it manually. Very easy, following http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html

> Extract the contents of the zip file in the eclipse/dropins folder and restart Eclipse.

Comment: Will uninstalling remove the settings for PyDev? Since only "debug" seems to be affected and I don't need it right now I'd rather not try it and lose my settings.

Comment: I had again to downgrade because PyDev upgraded automatically... and the interpreter for ex. is already set inside PyDev, without me doing anything.